# Prove that the discriminant of a degree $n$ polynomial f is a polynomial of degree $2n - 2$ in the coefficients of $f$

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, discriminant

The discriminant of some some degree $n$ polynomial
$$
f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0
$$
is given by
$$
\Delta_f = a_n^{2n-2} \prod\limits_{i < j} (\alpha_i - \alpha_j)^2
$$
where $\alpha_0, \dots, \alpha_n$ are the roots of $f$.

I have [seen](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialDiscriminant.html) it stated that the discriminant is always a homogenous polynomial of degree $2n - 2$ in the coefficients of $f$, $a_n, \dots, a_0$, but I have yet to see this proven.

One can easily calculate the discriminant for some low degrees and see that this holds, but what approach could I use to show that it holds in general?

Comment: If it is a polynomial, then it has to be homogenous, because for any non-zero $\lambda$, $f$ and $\lambda f$ has the same roots and therefore the same discriminant.

Comment: @Typhon: no need to be rude. This seems to be the OP's first question on this site, so maybe you are right and s/he is not a "real mathematician."  But that doesn't mean that the OP doesn't have the right to be treated with respect.

Comment: @Typhon Also, while we do encourage self-contained questions, the link provided in the question does give a concrete definition to work with. And I don't think we should let "equation" be the standard by which we judge questions. Words can be just as good as symbols, depending on the context, and many of the best questions on this site has not a single mathematical symbol in them.

Comment: @Typhon I apologize, I edited the post to include the definition I am referring to. I (incorrectly I suppose) assumed that was usually the only definition of the discriminant.

Answer (score 3):

The discriminant of a univariate polynomial $f$ is the resultant of $f$ and of its derivative $f'$.

So let's take a step back to talk about resultants. Let $f$, $g$ be two univariate polynomials of degree $d$ and $e$ respectively. Then the resultant is a polynomial in the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ that arises as the determinant of the Sylvester matrix. See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition) on resultant. The Sylvester matrix has size $d+e$.

In particular if $f$ is univariate of degree $n$, its derivative has degree $n-1$, so the resultant of $f$ and $f'$ has degree $2n-1$. However, you can see that you can factor out $a_n$ from the Sylvester matrix (depending on how you write it, the first row or the first column will be a multiple of $a_n$). This tells you that the resultant of $f$ and $f'$ is $a_n \cdot \Delta$ where $\Delta$ is some polynomial in the coefficients of $f$. That $\Delta$ is the discriminant.

Comment: How is this different from my answer ?

Comment: It is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant is the resultant of the polynomial and its derivative. This gives a square matrix in the coefficients of size $n+(n-1)=2n-1$.
I suspect that the final reduction comes from the fact that $a_0$ will be common to all terms and it is cancelled.