# Defining discriminant of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, discriminant

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant), the discriminant of a polynomial $f(x)=a_nx^n+$(lower degree terms) is defined in terms of roots of $f(x)$ as
$$
D(f)=a_n^{2n-2}\prod_{i<j} (\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^2.
$$
My question is simple, but I am not able to find answer: why the coefficient $a_n$ is taken with power $2n-2$ in the definition of discriminant? (Lang in his Algebra mentions same expression for $D(f)$, p.204.)

To ask more precisely, the above quantity depends on the roots of $f(x)$ (and independent of ordering of roots); since a monic polynomial $\tilde{f}$ and $a_n\tilde{f}$ (with $a_n\neq 0$) have same roots, one may ignore $a_n$ in defining discriminant. But, if **one wants to consider leading coefficient** in defining discriminant, why it is taken, as above, with power $2n-2$? Not $n$ or $2n$?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463593/prove-that-the-discriminant-of-a-degree-n-polynomial-f-is-a-polynomial-of-degr?rq=1) can help you.

Comment: We want the discriminant to be an integer, if the coefficients of $f$ are integers. That's the power of $a_n$ you need.